# Q&A: How can I get an instance of the contract by its address?

Tags: contract-invocation, ethereum-classic

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know **abi** to get the contract by its address

```
new web3.eth.Contract(contractJSON.abi, deployedAddress)
```